# Why can't I open the 'Downloads' directory?

Tags: directory, downloads

For some reason, the Downloads folder is inaccessible to me.

It does not display in the terminal when I use the
command `ls -al`, and when I used the GUI files
manager to open it, it displayed an error message,
in which it read, "Unable to find the requested file."

Comment: If it's not listed in `ls -al ~`, then it's been deleted.

Comment: @user535733 It's not listed. Would there be any way to recover it, or reinstall it on my system?

Comment: If it's in your Trash, then it can be recovered. If not, then recovery is both tedious and hit-or-miss. To create a new empty Downloads directory, simply create it and name it "Downloads". There's no other magic.

Comment: @user535733 Understood. Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

If `ls -la ~` is not listing it, the folder was deleted. Otherwise, you may have to check user permissions.

If it was deleted, you can either check the Trash and recover it, or simply create a folder in your home directory called "Downloads".

Answer (score 0):

If the Downloads folder for your user was deleted, you can just remake it:

```
mkdir ~/Downloads
```

Comment: It is in `/home/<username>/Downloads`

Comment: @Max thanks for catching this. Good thing the command is the same.